# How to change my PHP foreach looped SQL-Insert into a prepared-statement SQL loop?

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I have a looped query to do inserts into the MySQL database it works perfectly to do what I need it to do as in it takes all the users inputs in array and then loops them and inputs each into their own row in the database.

```
$sql_insert_race_history = "INSERT INTO inf_race_history 
                                    (`inf_id`,`race_history`, `results`) 
                            VALUES ";

if ($vracehistory != '') {
    foreach ($vracehistory as $kay => $value) {
        // $sql .= '' | $sql = $sql . '';
        $sql_insert_race_history .= "('$inserted_id','{$value}','{$results[$kay]}'),";
    }
} else {
    $vracehistory = '';
}
// remove last `,` into query;
$sql_insert_race_history = rtrim($sql_insert_race_history, ',');
$countRow = count($_POST['racehist']);
//INSERT INTO THE DATABASE VIA QUERY
$results_racehistory = mysqli_query($vconn, $sql_insert_race_history);
```

This code works and inserts everything as i need it However i have been told that it is vulnerable to SQL injections attacks, so i have been trying to prevent that by using prepared statements every version I try only so far loops the dont work and it only uploads the very last item in the array

```
$stmtrace = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO inf_race_history 
                                   (`inf_id`,`race_history`, `results`) 
                            VALUES (?,?,?)");
if ($vracehistory != '') {
    foreach ($vracehistory as $kay => $value) {
        $stmtrace->bind_param("sss", $inserted_id,$value,$results[$kay]);
    }
} else {
    $vracehistory = '';
}
// remove last `,` into query;
$sql_insert_race_history = rtrim($stmtrace, ',');
$countRow = count($_POST['racehist']);
//INSERT INTO THE DATABASE VIA QUERY
$stmtrace->execute();
```

I think it may have something to do with changing it from `.=` in the foreach loop to just `->bind_param` as maybe that is taking away the opportunity to loop it ? tho im not too sure and also how would i echo that i try to echo `$stmtrace` tho it says `method _tostring is not implemented`

Comment: There are much wrong with that code. First off, you prepare, and later execute, the query every time, but you're only binding params if `$vracehistory` isn't empty. Also, you can't `rtrim()` a statement. The statement isn't a string. Then you need to execute the statement before binding new variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($vracehistory as $kay => $value) {
    $stmtrace->bind_param("sss", $inserted_id, $value, $results[$kay]);
    $stmtrace->execute();
}
```

Comment: could i ask you when should i close the connection to the `stmt` and `$conn`?

Answer (score 0):

You should place execute() inside loop.

Comment: okay ill try that now and let you know, also do i put the other information also inside the loop?

Comment: did not work unlesss i may have done sotmething wrong but i put the `execute()` inside the loop

Comment: `if ($vracehistory != '') {
            foreach ($vracehistory as $kay => $value) {
                $stmtrace->bind_param("sss", $inserted_id,$value,$results[$kay]);
                $stmtrace->execute();
            }
        } else {
            $vracehistory = '';
        } `

Comment: hey i see it does work Kabir show me that it did work when i copied his so i think i may have just had slight error. you was correct

Answer (score 0):

bind the params outside the foreach loop, and assign and execute the query when you assign the variables inside the foreach loop. For example

```
$stmtrace->bind_param("sss", $insertId, $insertValue, $insertKey);
foreach ($vracehistory as $kay => $value) {
    $insertId = inserted_id;
    $insertValue = $value;
    $insertKey = $kay;
    $stmtrace->execute();
}
```

Another note, if you bind an integer, the value of the bind_param method should be 'i'.

Comment: hey @kezufru, that makes sense i see i did the bind inside of the loop insdead of stating the bind and then looping the values Just one issue with it tho, the second values where you have `$insertKey = $kay` does not actualy reflect in database it just shows up as a 0 or 1 or 2 depending on howmany inputs i actually input into database so if i do 2 then first one get a 0 and second one gets a 1